# Subquery with max value in a big table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a query to get the date of last work experience of a person and also the date they left the company (in some cases that value is null because the person is still working on the company).

I have something like:

```
  SELECT r.idcurriculum, r.startdate, r.lastdate FROM (
            SELECT idcurriculum, max(startdate) as startdate
            FROM workexperience
           GROUP BY idcurriculum) as s 
       INNER JOIN workexperience r on (r.idcurriculum = s.idcurriculum)
```

The structure should come out something like this:

```
idcurriculum | startdate | lastdate

1234         | 2010-05-01| null
2532         | 2005-10-01| 2010-02-28
5234         | 2011-07-01| 2013-10-31
1025         | 2012-04-01| 2014-03-31
```

I tried running that query but I had to stop it because it was taking too long. The **workexperience** table  weights aprox 20GB. I don't know if the query is wrong, I've only run it for 10 minutes.

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try rephrasing the query as:

```
select r.*
from workexperience we
where not exists (select 1
                  from workexperience we2
                  where we2.idcurriculum = we.idcurriculum and
                        we2.startdate > we.startdate
                 );
```

Important:  for performance reasons you need a composite index on `idcurriculum`, `startdate`:

```
create index idx_workexperience_idcurriculum_startdate on workexperience(idcurriculum, strtdate)
```

The logic of the query is:  "Get me all rows from `workexperience` where there is no row for the same `idcurriculum` that has a larger `startdate`".  That is a fancy way of saying "get me the maximum".

With the `group by`, MySQL has to do an aggregation, which would typically involve sorting the data -- expensive on 20 Gbytes.  With this method, it can look up the results using the index, which should be faster.

Comment: I´m completely new using indexes, do I have to run that part first and then the query? Is it possible to run indexes with read only permissions?(I tried to run the query and it was denied)

Comment: I ran the query without the index and it still works perfect. 0.344 seconds. Thnx for your help.

Comment: @Pietro . . . That is a very fast result on 20 Gbytes of data.  Perhaps the index already existed.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Gordon's answer you could also write the query as:

```
    SELECT r.*
      FROM work_experience we
 LEFT JOIN work_experience we2
        ON we2.idcurriculum = we.idcurriculum
       AND we2.startdate > we.startdate
     WHERE we2.idcurriculum IS NULL;
```

You can run into problems when there are multiple maximum start_dates in the group however.